# Tracing Blockchain.com Wallet-ID from Receiver Address. Address Re-use

Tags: blockchain

I am wanted to question related to **blockchain.com** ?

1. If i have some one BTC to BTC receiver address can i trace name or wallet id or something?
2. For example if i generate multiple btc to btc receiver address can we trace the wallet id?
3. If i use old btc to btc receiver id is this OK? When it will be expire? Is these receiver id goes to expire.?

Looking forward for reply.
Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

> If i have some one BTC to BTC receiver address can i trace name or wallet id or something?

Generally no. Blockchain.com might be able to. That's why I would be wary of using their "wallet" and why I'd use one of the non-custodial wallet (self-custodial wallet) listed at https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

> if i generate multiple btc to btc receiver address can we trace the wallet id?

No.

> If i use old btc to btc receiver id is this OK?

If by "receiver id" you mean the receiving bitcoin address, yes, it is OK so long as you have a real (non-custodial) wallet.

If you gave your money to someone else to look after for you, then all bets are off. They can make up their own rules to separate you from your money.

> When it will be expire? Is these receiver id goes to expire.?

Bitcoin addresses never expire. It is preferable to avoid reuse for privacy reasons because all transactions are public and people can infer information about you from patterns of usage.

If you gave your money to someone else to look after for you, then all bets are off. They can make up their own rules to separate you from your money.

---

Related questions:

- [What kinds of wallets are there?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866)
- [How can there exist businesses that "specialize in blockchain analysis looking for patterns of usage that reveal how money is being used"?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/95902/13866)
- [When you make a Bitcoin transaction, can the receiving person (and the world?) really see how much coins you have in the entire wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/106066/13866)
- [Bitcoins Anonymity - Do Exchanges Break It?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103304/13866)